# Save Unity Console log/ crash report from code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, crash-reports, unity-editor

```
void Awake()   
{
    Application.logMessageReceived += onLogMessageReceived;
}
void onLogMessageReceived(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
{
    output = logString;
    stack = stackTrace;
    log_type = type;
    if (log_type == LogType.Error || log_type == LogType.Exception)
    {
        writeReportInFile();
    }
}
```

I am using "Application.logMessageReceived += onLogMessageReceived" to save logs in case of Exceptions, Errors etc, at run time in the game. So my question is, is onLogMessageReceived() method also gets called when crash happens or can we also save logs in case of crash (if app gets crashed at run time)? and does it also catches StackOverFlowExceptions? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? Isn't it anyway already included in the normal [Player Log](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/LogFiles.html) and I'm unsure but I think indeed it might work even after crash / exceptions you can usually still see in the log something about Unity closing the app ... have you tried? Btw what if `writeReportInFile` itself causes an exception / log ? ^^

Comment: I want to create a system which will automate the process of saving logs in a file or on server in release build too in case of any exception or crash. In Player Log we have to check log manually and device must be connected through editor or any profiling tools(adb, android etc). I am able to do that in case of error and exception, I am not sure it will work in case of CRASH as well. So...  @derHugo

Comment: This is always a bit of a tricky situation. How exactly do you expect a program that crashed to still execute something that performs an upload of data? ;) Usually in such case you would start a "hidden" parallel program - let's call it CrashHandler. This basically completely separate process connects to the actual application e.g. via TCP and listens and logs the events. Additionally it can then handle a clean closing of the TCP connection e.g. via a specific message from the main app => If the connection suddenly is closed without that it means the app crashed or was force closed

Comment: Yes, You right, that's where I have been stuck and trying to find the answer, because Unity is doing that, they are sending their crash report on their cloud, so there must be a way. If Unity app gets crashed then how Unity saves and sends their log, I am finding a way something like that. @derHugo